# An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' for XNA Game

Tags: xna

I keep getting this message:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' on the code below:

```
        if (position.X >= p.position.X && position.X != p.position.X)
            position.X -= Yspeed;
        if (position.X >= p.position.X && position.X != p.position.X)
            position.X += Yspeed;
        position.Y = position.Y + Yspeed;
```

Specifically refers to the first line. What i'm trying to do is move the enemy towards the player.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing a field or method of a null reference:

```
MyType instance = null;

// Throws a NullReferenceException because instance is 
// not an actual object but null.
instance.Name = "foo";
```

So I suppose `position` or, rather `p` is unset. If you are using an IDE like Visual Studio use a breakpoint and inspect your variables and check if they actually contain something.

Comment: It would have to be p if position is a Vector2. Structs are always initialized to a default value.

Comment: Yes, yet we don't actually see the declaration of `position` nor the type definition. It could just as well be a class. But I'm fairly certain that you are right.